# Record not inserting into MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have created mongodb database 'employee' and collection 'personal' into the database. Now I'm trying to connect the db using php, it's connecting but when I'm trying to insert data into the collections, nothing is happened, here is my script :

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
    error_reporting(0);
   $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

   echo "Connection to database successfully"."<br>";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->employee;

   echo "Database selected"."<br>";

   $collection = $db->personal;

   echo "Collection selected"."<br>";

   $collection->insertOne(["name"=>"Rajib", "address"=>"Delhi", "contact"=>123, "gender"=>"Male", "dept"=>"PHP"]);


   echo "Document inserted successfully";
?>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Change the error report line to this and tell what is the error   error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: the following errors are showing ```Connection to database successfully

Notice: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$employee in C:\xampp\htdocs\suman_php\php-mongo\connection.php on line 9
Database selected

Notice: Trying to get property 'personal' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\suman_php\php-mongo\connection.php on line 13
Collection selected

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insertOne() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\suman_php\php-mongo\connection.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\suman_php\php-mongo\connection.php on line 17```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, after updating composer then reinstalling mongodb using composer